# How do I shorten this grid-movement logic with a loop (python)

Tags: python, logic, refactoring

I feel kinda stupid for typing all this out knowing that there must be a way shorter way to do it. But it just didn't come to me.

I want to shorten this with a for or a while loop but for the life of me I just can't visualize what this would look like. If you can't tell what I'm trying to do is change the values of a 2d list (move them) essentially in a random 9 direction setting.

```
def move_agents(agent_location):
 """Randomly generates a movement pattern for each agent and moves them
 accordingly. Agents have 9 possible movements, 8 being directions, and the last
 being not moving"""
 #Generate random directions for each agent
 move_agent_1 = random_gen(2)
 move_agent_2 = random_gen(2)
 move_agent_3 = random_gen(2)
 move_agent_4 = random_gen(2)
 move_agent_5 = random_gen(2)
 move_agent_6 = random_gen(2)

 #All Agent 1 movements
 if (move_agent_1 == 1):
      #Up left
      agent_location[0][0] = int(agent_location[0][0]) - 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][0] = int(agent_location[1][0]) - 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_1 == 2):
      #Up
      agent_location[0][0] = int(agent_location[0][0]) - 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][0] = int(agent_location[1][0]) #Column

 elif (move_agent_1 == 3):
      #Up Right
      agent_location[0][0] = int(agent_location[0][0]) - 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][0] = int(agent_location[1][0]) + 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_1 == 4):
      #Left
      agent_location[0][0] = int(agent_location[0][0])  #Row
      agent_location[1][0] = int(agent_location[1][0]) - 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_1 == 5):
      #No move
      agent_location[0][0] = int(agent_location[0][0]) #Row
      agent_location[1][0] = int(agent_location[1][0]) #Column
 elif (move_agent_1 == 6):
      #Right
      agent_location[0][0] = int(agent_location[0][0]) #Row
      agent_location[1][0] = int(agent_location[1][0]) + 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_1 == 7):
      #Down left
      agent_location[0][0] = int(agent_location[0][0]) + 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][0] = int(agent_location[1][0]) - 1#Column
 elif (move_agent_1 == 8):
      #Down
      agent_location[0][0] = int(agent_location[0][0]) + 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][0] = int(agent_location[1][0]) #Column
 elif (move_agent_1 == 9):
      #Down right
      agent_location[0][0] = int(agent_location[0][0]) + 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][0] = int(agent_location[1][0]) + 1 #Column

 #All Agent 2 movements
 if (move_agent_2 == 1):
      #Up left
      agent_location[0][1] = int(agent_location[0][1]) - 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][1] = int(agent_location[1][1]) - 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_2 == 2):
      #Up
      agent_location[0][1] = int(agent_location[0][1]) - 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][1] = int(agent_location[1][1]) #Column
 elif (move_agent_2 == 3):
      #Up Right
      agent_location[0][1] = int(agent_location[0][1]) - 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][1] = int(agent_location[1][1]) + 1#Column
 elif (move_agent_2 == 4):
      #Left
      agent_location[0][1] = int(agent_location[0][1]) #Row
      agent_location[1][1] = int(agent_location[1][1]) -1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_2 == 5):
      #No move
      agent_location[0][1] = int(agent_location[0][1]) #Row
      agent_location[1][1] = int(agent_location[1][1]) #Column
 elif (move_agent_2 == 6):
      #Right
      agent_location[0][1] = int(agent_location[0][1]) #Row
      agent_location[1][1] = int(agent_location[1][1]) + 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_2 == 7):
      #Down left
      agent_location[0][1] = int(agent_location[0][1]) + 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][1] = int(agent_location[1][1]) - 1#Column
 elif (move_agent_2 == 8):
      #Down
      agent_location[0][1] = int(agent_location[0][1]) #Row
      agent_location[1][1] = int(agent_location[1][1]) + 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_2 == 9):
      #Down right
      agent_location[0][1] = int(agent_location[0][1]) + 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][1] = int(agent_location[1][1]) + 1 #Column

 #All Agent 3 movements   
 if (move_agent_3 == 1):
      #Up left
      agent_location[0][2] = int(agent_location[0][2]) - 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][2] = int(agent_location[1][2]) - 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_3 == 2):
      #Up
      agent_location[0][2] = int(agent_location[0][2]) - 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][2] = int(agent_location[1][2]) #Column
 elif (move_agent_3 == 3):
      #Up Right
      agent_location[0][2] = int(agent_location[0][2]) - 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][2] = int(agent_location[1][2]) + 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_3 == 4):
      #Left
      agent_location[0][2] = int(agent_location[0][2]) #Row
      agent_location[1][2] = int(agent_location[1][2]) - 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_3 == 5):
      #No move
      agent_location[0][2] = int(agent_location[0][2]) #Row
      agent_location[1][2] = int(agent_location[1][2]) #Column
 elif (move_agent_3 == 6):
      #Right
      agent_location[0][2] = int(agent_location[0][2]) #Row
      agent_location[1][2] = int(agent_location[1][2]) + 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_3 == 7):
      #Down left
      agent_location[0][2] = int(agent_location[0][2]) + 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][2] = int(agent_location[1][2]) - 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_3 == 8):
      #Down
      agent_location[0][2] = int(agent_location[0][2]) + 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][2] = int(agent_location[1][2]) #Column
 elif (move_agent_3 == 9):
      #Down right
      agent_location[0][2] = int(agent_location[0][2]) + 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][2] = int(agent_location[1][2]) + 1 #Column

 #All Agent 4 movements
 if (move_agent_4 == 1):
      #Up left
      agent_location[0][3] = int(agent_location[0][3]) - 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][3] = int(agent_location[1][3]) - 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_4 == 2):
      #Up
      agent_location[0][3] = int(agent_location[0][3]) - 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][3] = int(agent_location[1][3]) #Column
 elif (move_agent_4 == 3):
      #Up Right
      agent_location[0][3] = int(agent_location[0][3]) - 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][3] = int(agent_location[1][3]) - 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_4 == 4):
      #Left
      agent_location[0][3] = int(agent_location[0][3]) #Row
      agent_location[1][3] = int(agent_location[1][3]) - 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_4 == 5):
      #No move
      agent_location[0][3] = int(agent_location[0][3]) #Row
      agent_location[1][3] = int(agent_location[1][3]) #Column
 elif (move_agent_4 == 6):
      #Right
      agent_location[0][3] = int(agent_location[0][3]) #Row
      agent_location[1][3] = int(agent_location[1][3]) + 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_4 == 7):
      #Down left
      agent_location[0][3] = int(agent_location[0][3]) + 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][3] = int(agent_location[1][3]) - 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_4 == 8):
      #Down
      agent_location[0][3] = int(agent_location[0][3]) + 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][3] = int(agent_location[1][3]) #Column
 elif (move_agent_4 == 9):
      #Down right
      agent_location[0][3] = int(agent_location[0][3]) + 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][3] = int(agent_location[1][3]) + 1 #Column

 #All agent 5 movements
 if (move_agent_5 == 1):
      #Up left
      agent_location[0][4] = int(agent_location[0][4]) - 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][4] = int(agent_location[1][4]) - 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_5 == 2):
      #Up
      agent_location[0][4] = int(agent_location[0][4]) - 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][4] = int(agent_location[1][4]) #Column
 elif (move_agent_5 == 3):
      #Up Right
      agent_location[0][4] = int(agent_location[0][4]) - 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][4] = int(agent_location[1][4]) + 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_5 == 4):
      #Left
      agent_location[0][4] = int(agent_location[0][4]) #Row
      agent_location[1][4] = int(agent_location[1][4]) - 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_5 == 5):
      #No move
      agent_location[0][4] = int(agent_location[0][4]) #Row
      agent_location[1][4] = int(agent_location[1][4]) #Column
 elif (move_agent_5 == 6):
      #Right
      agent_location[0][4] = int(agent_location[0][4]) #Row
      agent_location[1][4] = int(agent_location[1][4]) + 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_5 == 7):
      #Down left
      agent_location[0][4] = int(agent_location[0][4]) + 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][4] = int(agent_location[1][4]) - 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_5 == 8):
      #Down
      agent_location[0][4] = int(agent_location[0][4]) + 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][4] = int(agent_location[1][4]) #Column
 elif (move_agent_5 == 9):
      #Down right
      agent_location[0][4] = int(agent_location[0][4]) + 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][4] = int(agent_location[1][4]) + 1 #Column

 #All agent 6 movements    
 if (move_agent_6 == 1):
      #Up left
      agent_location[0][5] = int(agent_location[0][5]) - 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][5] = int(agent_location[1][5]) - 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_6 == 2):
      #Up
      agent_location[0][5] = int(agent_location[0][5]) - 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][5] = int(agent_location[1][5]) #Column
 elif (move_agent_6 == 3):
      #Up Right
      agent_location[0][5] = int(agent_location[0][5]) - 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][5] = int(agent_location[1][5]) + 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_6 == 4):
      #Left
      agent_location[0][5] = int(agent_location[0][5]) #Row
      agent_location[1][5] = int(agent_location[1][5]) - 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_6 == 5):
      #No move
      agent_location[0][5] = int(agent_location[0][5]) #Row
      agent_location[1][5] = int(agent_location[1][5]) #Column
 elif (move_agent_6 == 6):
      #Right
      agent_location[0][5] = int(agent_location[0][5]) #Row
      agent_location[1][5] = int(agent_location[1][5]) + 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_6 == 7):
      #Down left
      agent_location[0][5] = int(agent_location[0][5]) + 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][5] = int(agent_location[1][5]) - 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent_6 == 8):
      #Down
      agent_location[0][5] = int(agent_location[0][5]) + 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][5] = int(agent_location[1][5]) #Column
 elif (move_agent_6 == 9):
      #Down right
      agent_location[0][5] = int(agent_location[0][5]) + 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][5] = int(agent_location[1][5]) + 1 #Column
```

Comment: As your code is working it is off-topic here, this is more suitable for [Codreview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Oh thank you. I actually didn't know there was a proper subforum!

Comment: And it's working, but do you really consider that code? That's a pretty nasty looking function.

Comment: But since you're performing an identical task 6 times in a row on each move_agent_1..6, that's a huge code hint you should have refactored that into six calls to the same function definition. @sweber goes even better and just inlines it into the `for x in range(0,6)` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure more can be done, but let's start by dividing your code length by 6

```
def move_agents(agent_location):
 move_agent = [random_gen(2) for x in range(0, 6)]

for x in range(0,6):
 if (move_agent[x] == 0):
      #Up left
      agent_location[0][x] = int(agent_location[0][x]) - 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][x] = int(agent_location[1][x]) - 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent[x] == 1):
      #Up
      agent_location[0][x] = int(agent_location[0][x]) - 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][x] = int(agent_location[1][x]) #Column

 elif (move_agent[x] == 2):
      #Up Right
      agent_location[0][x] = int(agent_location[0][x]) - 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][x] = int(agent_location[1][x]) + 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent[x] == 3):
      #Left
      agent_location[0][x] = int(agent_location[0][x])  #Row
      agent_location[1][x] = int(agent_location[1][x]) - 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent[x] == 4):
      #No move
      agent_location[0][x] = int(agent_location[0][x]) #Row
      agent_location[1][x] = int(agent_location[1][x]) #Column
 elif (move_agent[x] == 5):
      #Right
      agent_location[0][x] = int(agent_location[0][x]) #Row
      agent_location[1][x] = int(agent_location[1][x]) + 1 #Column
 elif (move_agent[x] == 6):
      #Down left
      agent_location[0][x] = int(agent_location[0][x]) + 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][x] = int(agent_location[1][x]) - 1#Column
 elif (move_agent[x] == 7):
      #Down
      agent_location[0][x] = int(agent_location[0][x]) + 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][x] = int(agent_location[1][x]) #Column
 elif (move_agent[x] == 8):
      #Down right
      agent_location[0][x] = int(agent_location[0][x]) + 1 #Row
      agent_location[1][x] = int(agent_location[1][x]) + 1 #Column
```

with a bit of further shortening :

```
 def move_agents(agent_location):
      move_agent = [random_gen(2) for x in range(0, 6)]

      for x in range(0,6):
      #up
           if move_agent[x] <= [0, 1, 2] :
                agent_location[0][x] = int(agent_location[0][x]) - 1 #Row
      #down
           if move_agent[x] in [6, 7, 8] :
                agent_location[0][x] = int(agent_location[0][x]) + 1 #Row
      #left
           if move_agent[x] in [0, 3, 6] :
                agent_location[1][x] = int(agent_location[1][x]) - 1#Column
      #right
           if move_agent[x] in [2, 5, 8] :
                agent_location[1][x] = int(agent_location[1][x]) + 1#Column
```

Comment: OH WOW. I never even considered the idea about x being an element in the list. That's great!

Comment: I fixed a bug in the indexes

Answer (score 2):

OK, lets improve it more.

This `move_agent[x]` ranging from 1 to 9 gives this pattern:

```
123
456
789
```

So if your agent moves, it is like it starts on field `5` and goes to the field with the number of `move_agent[x]`

So, here is the direction where it moves:

```
deltaX=(move_agent[x]-1)%3 -1
deltaX=(move_agent[x]-1)/3 -1
```

It gives you this patterns:

```
   deltaX              deltaY
-1   0   +1         -1   -1   -1
-1   0   +1          0    0    0
-1   0   +1         +1   +1   +1
```

**Now, here is the code:**

```
for x in range(0,6):
    deltaX=(move_agent[x]-1)%3 -1
    deltaX=(move_agent[x]-1)/3 -1
    agent_location[0][x] = int(agent_location[0][x]) + deltaX #Row
    agent_location[1][x] = int(agent_location[1][x]) +deltaY  #Column
```

so, the moving is condensed to 5 lines. You can replace the deltaX/Y in the last rows by the calculation itself and spare two more lines...

Answer (score 0):

I would also extract one method, you have lots of duplicate code.

```
def updateArray(agent_location, rowVal, colVal):
  agent_location[0][x] = int(agent_location[0][x]) + rowVal #Row
  agent_location[1][x] = int(agent_location[1][x]) + colVal #colVal
  return agent_location

def move_agents(agent_location):
 move_agent = [random_gen(2) for x in range(0, 6)]

 for x in range(0,6):
  if (move_agent[x] == 1):
   #Up left
   agent_location = updateArray(agent_location, -1, -1)
  elif (move_agent[x] == 2):
   #Up
   agent_location = updateArray(agent_location, -1, 0)
  ...
```

Comment: What are those { } braces doing around your function updateArray? :) This ain't C, baby...

Comment: Damn it, I was currently doing some Java:P thanks for your mark:)

Answer (score 0):

Why not exploit the fact that if you have nine directions (one of which is no direction), you can represent the problem like this:

```
Dir  Up/None/Down  Left/None/Right
0    -1            -1
1    -1             0
2    -1            +1
3     0            -1
4     0             0
5     0            +1
6    +1            -1
7    +1             0
8    +1            +1
```

where -1 is down/left, and +1 is up/right.

Then you can get really simple with your function:

```
import random


def move_agents(locations):
    ROW = 0
    COL = 1
    for i in locations:
        rnd = int(random.random()*9)
        i[ROW] += (rnd % 3) - 1
        i[COL] += (rnd / 3) - 1
    return locations

def main():
    iterations = 20
    locations = [[1,2],[4,1],[3,3],[2,1],[0,0],[7,2],[1,1],[8,4],[5,5]]
    print(locations)
    for i in range(iterations):
        locations = move_agents(locations)
        print(locations)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```